# How to make a new column by lists of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a new column based on the other column. The column `C` is a list of words. I want to make lists of all pairs. For example consider 2 rows of the column C as below!

```
Existing column "C" 
[‘a’,’b’,’c’]
[‘g’,’h’, ‘j’]
```

I want the new column to be like this:

```
New column
[‘a’, ‘b’],[‘a’, ‘c’],[‘b’, ‘c’]
[‘g’, ‘h’],[‘g’, ‘j’],[‘h’, ‘j’]
```

I know how to do that by using list’s method. For example the following:

```
List_words=Df[‘C].tolist()
pairs_of_skills=[]
for l in List_words:
    Each=[]
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
            if j!=i:      
               Each.append(sorted([l[j],l[i]]))

    pairs_of_skills.append(pairs_of_skills)
```

And then `Each` can be a new column. But I am looking for a more efficient method. I have a huge data set with large sets. Is there any faster method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> df['C'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2)))
0    [(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)]
1    [(g, h), (g, j), (h, j)]
Name: C, dtype: object
>>>
```

As a new `DataFrame`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['C'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))).to_numpy(), columns=['New Column'])
                 New Column
0  [(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)]
1  [(g, h), (g, j), (h, j)]
>>>
```

Or with `assign` and `pop`:

```
>>> df.assign(**{'New Column': df.pop('C').apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2)))})
                 New Column
0  [(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)]
1  [(g, h), (g, j), (h, j)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can do the same in pyspark data frame?