# adding a new column in a csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I created this Python script that does sort of a right join between two csv files. In a few words it creates a new csv containing:

1. rows which exist in both files
2. rows which exist only in the second csv (should be the most recent one)

it should then add a new column named "present", in the fist case this column should have a value of 0, in the second should have a value of 1

```py
import csv

def compare_csv(csv1, csv2, output_file):
    rows_csv1 = []
    rows_csv2 = []
    result_rows = []
    unique_rows = []
    common_rows = []

    # Lettura del file CSV meno recente
    with open(csv1, 'r') as file1:
        csv_reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
        for row in csv_reader1:
            rows_csv1.append(row )

    # Lettura del file CSV più recente
    with open(csv2, 'r') as file2:
        csv_reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
        for row in csv_reader2:
            rows_csv2.append(row)

    # Confronto delle righe
    for row2 in rows_csv2:
        if row2 not in rows_csv1:
            result_rows.append(row2 + ["1"])
        elif row2 in rows_csv2 and row2 in rows_csv1:
            result_rows.append(row2 + ["0"])
        else:
            print(f"la riga {row} non è presente")



    # Scrittura delle righe nel file di output
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as result_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(result_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(result_rows)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv1 = input("Inserisci il percorso del file CSV meno recente: ")
    csv2 = input("Inserisci il percorso del file CSV più recente: ")
    output_file = "result.csv"

    compare_csv(csv1, csv2, output_file)
    print("Operazione completata. Il file 'result.csv' è stato creato.")
```

problem here is that the script is adding the new column with a name of "0.1" and adding "0.1" as values of that column

any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a new column by lists of a column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612424/how-to-make-a-new-column-by-lists-of-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: i'm actually not using pandas

Comment: ah ok :) However, pandas is pretty efficient

Comment: What about rows that are in the first csv, not not in the second csv?

Comment: I ran your solution and it seems OK. Do you have some sample data which causes the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your code it's show you just creating column not row

You can create new row by

```
writer.writerow([index,value])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please be more specifi c with that? where should i put your code?

Comment: You can do this in output_file first you create colum by csv_writer.writerows(coumn_name) after that you can used for loop like this for index, value in enumerate(result_rows): then in this loop you can add your value like writer.writerow([index+1,*value])